# Retro-engineering an application on Android

Tags: android, android-development

I'm trying to retrieve some personal data from an application that has completely disappeared from Google Play, and its author has answered none of my emails.

(I'm namely trying to retrieve a private key. I make the assumption it is stored in a keystore)

The problem is that I cannot succeed to find the files related to this application. Neither the executable or the files used to store data.

I have done `ls -lRa > search.log` at the root of an Android Terminal Emulator, so as to have the list of accessible files. And I have done several textual search on the content of the list of files.

Given an application on android, how to know where files used by the application are located ?

So as to retro-engineer or to have some clues about an android application, what could be a good start ?

Comment: see [Where to start?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6367/31260)

Comment: @gnat I think "what coudl be a good start" is a second question. The main question being, how to locate files used by an android application. And I also explain what I have already done. And also the "Where to start" question is not about **Very Large project** as in the reference you pointed me at.

Comment: [Android.SE](https://android.stackexchange.com/) is a better place to ask this question and is also more likely to get you a useful answer.

Comment: I already did some weeks ago, and got no answers.

Answer (score 1):

Using `ABD`, Android Debug Bridge, was a good start.
It allows to launch some linux commands in the terminal of a pc.

But I finally found more info in doing a little Android application with Android Studio, in which I call the `getFilesDir()` function.

The result was:

```
/data/data/my.package.name
```

But the content of other applications directory is not readable unless one have root rights.

https://android.stackexchange.com/a/175221/218449